# Is there a way to open multiple Word files for printing?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I have a folder full of MS Word files, and I need to print them all out.  There are 86 files, and strikes me as tedious to the extreme to open, print, and close all 86 of them.

Is there a way to print the whole lot of them in basically one operation?  Or at least, a way easier than opening, printing and closing 86 files?

Comment: Can't you select them all, right click and print? Depending on your OS of course..

Comment: OMG.  You're right, @Raystafarian.  So simple it never occurred to me.  Makes my question seem rather stupid.  Arrgh.

Comment: +1 Nothing wrong with this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no out-of box solution to cycle through all files and print them automatically from Windows. What you can do is select them all and right-click, then select Print.

Note that Word will use your default printer and print settings, so make sure they are properly set in advance.

Comment: +1 for reminding him of "default printer and print settings"

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select all the file you want in explorer and right click to print.

Also, you can go to the folder in a command prompt and type `print *.docx`

Answer (score 1):

Select all and then right click - print.